# C++; Putting characters into a C-Style string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I've been reading a book for self study ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321992784](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321992784)) and I'm on chapter 17 doing the exercises. One of them I solved, but I'm not satisfied and would like some help. Thank you in advanced.

The Exercise: Write a program that reads characters from cin into an array that you allocate on the free store. Read indvidual characters until an exclamation mark(!) is entered. Do not use std::string. Do not worry about memory exhaustion.

What I did:

```
char* append(const char* str, char ch); // Add a character to the string and return a duplicate
char* loadCstr(); // Read characters from cin into an array of characters

int main()
{
    char* str{ loadCstr() };

    std::cout << str << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I made 2 functions, 1 to create a new string with a size 1 larger than the old and add a character at the end.

```
char* append(const char* str, char ch)
/*
    Create a new string with a size 1 greater than the old
    insert old string into new
    add character into new string
*/
{
    char* newstr{ nullptr };

    int i{ 0 };

    if (str)
        newstr = new char [ sizeof(str) + 2 ];
    else
        newstr = new char [ 2 ];

    if(str)
        while (str [ i ] != '\0')
            newstr [ i ] = str [ i++ ]; // Put character into new string, then increment the index

    newstr [ i++ ] = ch; // Add character and increment the index
    newstr [ i ] = '\0'; // Trailing 0

    return newstr;
}
```

This is the function for the exercise using the append function I created, It works, but from what I understand each time I call append, there is a memory leak because I create a new character array and didn't delete the old.

```
char* loadCstr()
/*
    get a character from cin, append it to str until !
*/
{
    char* str{ nullptr };

    for (char ch; std::cin >> ch && ch != '!';)
        str = append(str, ch);

    return str;
}
```

I tried adding another pointer to hold the old array and delete it after making a new one, but after about 6 calls in this loop I get a runtime error that I think tells me I'm deleting something I shouldn't? which is where I got confused.

This is the old one that doesn't work beyond 6 characters:

```
char* loadCstr()
/*
    get a character from cin, append it to str until !
*/
{
    char* str{ nullptr };

    for (char ch; std::cin >> ch && ch != '!';) {

        char* temp{ append(str, ch) };

        if (str)
            delete str;

        str = temp;
    }
    return str;
}
```

So I want to know how I can fix this function so there are no memory leaks. Thank you again. (Also please note, I do know these functions already exist and using std::string handles all the free store stuff for me, I just want to understand it and this is a learning exercise.)

Comment: Let the caller free the memory

Comment: `sizeof(str)` and `strlen(str)` are not the same

Comment: @stackptr Yeah, when loadCstr() calls append I try to delete str before putting temp inside of it, but then I get a run-time error after the loop has 6 cycles. If I delete the string in main, doesn't that still mean each time I call append(str, ch)  i leak str?

Comment: Also `newstr [ i ] = str [ i++ ];` is undefined behavior (there's no sequencing between reading `i` on the left and incrementing it on the right).

Comment: @BenVoigt Ohhh, I understand now. I think it has to do with memory reserving only 4 bytes. I'm not sure if using strlen(str) would be cheating or not, but that did solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MattC: You definitely can write your own `lenStr` function if you don't want to "cheat" by using `strlen`.  The important difference is between the size of the pointer and the size of the data it points to.  `sizeof` can only tell you the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use standard C function `std::strlen` instead of the `sizeof` operator because in case of your function the `sizeof` operator returns the size of pointer instead of the length of the string.

Also you need to delete already allocated array.

The function can look the following way

```
char* append(const char* str, char ch)
/*
    Create a new string with a size 1 greater than the old
    insert old string into new
    add character into new string
*/
{
    size_t n = 0;

    if ( str ) n = std::strlen( str );

    char *newstr = new char[ n + 2 ];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) newstr[i] = str[i];

    delete [] str;

    newstr[n] = ch;
    newstr[n+1] = '\0';

    return newstr;
}
```

And in the function `loadCstr` it can be called like

```
str = append( str, ch );
```

Also instead of the loop to copy the string you could use standard algorithm `std::copy`

Comment: I was avoiding the standard library functions because this is a learning exercise, but your answer was still right. I recreated the strlen() and I am going to recreate copy, but the main problem was that I was using sizeof() which never gave me the actual number of characters in my string it only gave me the amount of bytes the string was using. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is the point to learn about memory management, or about how string operations work internally?

For the second (learning about string operations), you should use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` which will automatically free the attached array when the pointer dies.  You'll still need to calculate string length, copy between strings, append -- all the things you are doing now.  But `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` will handle the deallocation.

For the first case, you're better off writing an RAII class (custom version of `std::unique_ptr<T>`) and learning how to free memory in a destructor, than scattering `delete []` statements all over your code.  Writing `delete []` everywhere is actually a bad habit, learning it will move your ability to program C++ backwards.